# Smps with switching stage after transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

I'm trying to design and build an smps for hobbysts reasons. I would like to use isolation from the mains with a transformer.

Everywhere on the net I found that the transformer is connected after the switching stage (as in the flyback converter). Would it be ok to put the transformer before the switching stage as depicted in the image?

I assume that the only reason to put the transformer after the switching stage is to use a smaller transformer (because of higher switch frequency). I would like to put the transformer connected to the mains for safety reasons.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUs0e5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you use a 50/60 Hz rated one yes, but you’ll be missing out the main reason to use (primary switched) SMPSes - lightweight and cheap transformer.

Answer (score 6):

> *Would it be ok to put the transformer before the switching stage as
> depicted in the image?*

Providing that the transformer is suitable for use at 50/60 Hz and, is rated for your mains voltage then sure. But, you also need to make sure that it is a proper isolating transformer and not something picked out of a skip that may be severely compromised in safety aspects.

You should also be aware that this type of power supply arrangement does not offer a very good power factor. We didn't seem to care 30 years ago but these days we do so, if this were a commercial design, then I'd advise you to use a better topology.

Comment: What is the main cause of low power factor in my topology?

Comment: Bridge rectifiers only conduct current when the voltage waveform is near its peak due to the charged bulk capacitor on the output. This is the main cause. Of course the same can be true for many flyback converters but, beyond a certain power limit, you need to provide power factor correction @Dukenukem

Answer (score 6):

To clarify, using an iron-core transformer for a low voltage unregulated supply ahead of the SMPS, is called a "hybrid" supply.  Since it has elements of both a conventional linear supply (the fat transformer) and SMPS.

A low voltage buck converter has none of the safety issues, and is much less likely to encounter EMI problems, than a full (offline) SMPS.  You still need good layout, but the important part is you don't have hundreds of volts switching across an isolation barrier.  Instead more like just a couple volts, across a common ground path.  Which can be reduced to ~mV or less with good layout and a little filtering.

One more note: look for current mode controllers.  You will find many old (voltage mode) designs out there, from older books, to app notes, even recent ones (the crusty old TL494 remains in production and supported!).  If this is a design exercise, by all means, try both -- discover the difficulties of voltage mode controls (hard to compensate, slow performance, poor startup/fault behavior), the motivation for current mode, and the performance gains therein. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you've suggested, with the addition of a couple of diodes to rectify the output of the first transformer, is used in many places (avionics, for one), where the prime power is AC (400 Hz).  That first transformer, filter and my suggested rectifiers provide a source of unregulated DC current - what's called in some circles a bulk supply.

That unregulated DC is then fed into a standard SMPS (H-bridge on the input to the second transformer) with the transformer turns ratio and rectifiers (usually synchronous nowadays) plus filter to provide the regulated DC voltage you want.